# How can I create a keyvaluepair with a value two different data types?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I wrote a method that returns

```
List<KeyValuePair<CommandType, List<string>>>
```

`CommandType` is of Type `enum`

```
public enum CommandType
{
    Programmed,
    Manual
}
```

My issue is that the value in the `KeyValuePair` sometimes is an `enum`, and sometimes it is a list of strings, but I need to keep all the `KeyValuePair` in one list.

currently, I pass the value as an object in the keyvaluepair and when the method returns the list and an iterate through it, based on the key, I cast the value  back to its original type.

Is there a better way to implement this?

here is a sample code

```
public enum  ProgrammedCommands
{
    Sntp,
    Snmp,
}
private List<KeyValuePair<CommandType, object>> GetCommandsFromTemplate(string[] templateLines)
{
    var list = new List<KeyValuePair<CommandType, object>>();

    if (templateLines != null)
        for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < templateLines.Length; lineIndex++)
        {
            if (templateLines[lineIndex].Contains("!*") && templateLines[lineIndex].Contains("*!"))
            {
                KeyValuePair<CommandType, object> ProgrammedSetting;
                List<string> programmedCommandList;
                if (templateLines[lineIndex].Contains("SNTP - SNTP Server Commands"))
                {

                    ProgrammedSetting = new KeyValuePair<CommandType, object>(CommandType.Programmed, ProgrammedCommands.Sntp);
                    list.Add(ProgrammedSetting);
                }

                else if (templateLines[lineIndex].Contains("MANUAL"))
                {
                    lineIndex++;
                    List<string> manual = new List<string>();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (lineIndex >= templateLines.Length)
                            break;
                        if (templateLines[lineIndex].Contains("!!["))
                            lineIndex++;
                        else if (templateLines[lineIndex].Contains("]!!"))
                            break;
                        else
                        {
                            manual.Add(templateLines[lineIndex]);
                            lineIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                    ProgrammedSetting = new KeyValuePair<CommandType, object>(CommandType.Manual, manual);
                    list.Add(ProgrammedSetting);
                }
            }
        }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Dictionary<object, object>` or `List<KeyValuePair<object,object>>`?

Comment: Or you can do conversion: enum -> string -> enum

Comment: Write a class that has the properties you need and return a `List<T>` of that. What you've got is hard to read and hard to maintain. It's your life, but you're saving a tiny amount of time up front at the expense of endless hassle as long as you work on this code. `KeyValuePair` is a wildly inappropriate choice here.

Comment: i think a dictionary would be a proper choice since all i am doing is reading the values. what about the the rest of the implementation, any other way to keep a list of two different types besides using the object type and casting it back based on the key?

Comment: Since type of your object can be determined just at run-time, so don't look for a solution other than using `object`. You should box your values to an object and the if for any reason you want to know the type of object, you need to check its type and then unbox it to desired type.

Comment: @EdPlunkett "crazy" :) It can be bad suggestion, please choose words :). Why is it "crazy"?

Comment: @kat1330 Perhaps I misunderstood you. What exactly were you suggesting?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am here to learn and word "crazy" doesn't teach me anything. But words like: not efficient, bad practice... followed with some brief explanation can teach a lot.

Comment: @kat1330 I thought you were talking about parsing and stringifying enums all over. If I was mistaken, I very likely owe you an apology. What were you suggesting?

Comment: @EdPlunkett a List<T> won't solve the problem,because when I initialize the list which I will add my items to,I need to set the T to either a `ProgrammedCommand` or a `List<string>`, so two types can't be added to the same list. I think I need to create a class which has two properties, a `ProgrammedCommand` and a second property of type `object` then I can maintain a list of objects instantiated from the class, which will make the code cleaner. All i need to do is iterate through the list sequentially, nothing else!  so thanks for the suggestion @EdPunkett and thanks for the help @Reza Aghaei

Comment: @user3726459 I meant to make the T in `List<T>` a class that you write yourself: "A class that has the properties you need". The class, call it `CommandInfo` would have a CommandType property, a ProgrammedCommand property, and a `List<String>` property. Then you would have a `List<CommandInfo>` of instances of that class. It would replace KeyValuePair, make your code more readable, make Intellisense your friend, and solve your problem with the two types. I think we're on the same page now.

Comment: @EdPlunkett the second property is not always a `List<string>` sometimes it is an `Enum`

Comment: @EdPlunkett If for any reason you want to use a type `T` for storage other than `object` I guess you would like my suggestion in note part of the answer.

Comment: @user3726459 So add an enum property too. It's your class, add all the properties you want. By the way, a better choice than KeyValuePair would have been `Tuple<CommandType, List<String>, ProgrammedCommand, SomeOtherEnum>` -- I still very strongly urge writing your own class, but you can give a `Tuple` a lot of typed properties. The trouble is their names are `Item1`, `Item2` etc. -- just as uninformative as `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That approach works too. Toss in a few virtual methods and you're in business.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i guess I can do that too, but I was fixated on having two properties. I guess it will be easily readable than using an object type and casting it back. I will try both and see how the code looks. thanks

Comment: @kat1330 Probably "Crazy" is not a good word choice here and "ugly" or "awkward" may work better. But I guess there is no offensive purpose behind the word :)

Comment: @user3726459 Ah, I see. Having multiple strongly typed and properly named properties makes it much, much easier to write solid code. Type casts aren't evil, but they do add extra keystrokes and visual "noise" and you can only check their validity at runtime, which can easily lead to programming errors.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I meant about converting enum to string and then parsing string to enum. It is more complicate and less efficient then casting. When you said "crazy" did you point of something else?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I don't understand you properly: "But I guess there is no offensive purpose behind the word :)" I just want to know what means when solution is "crazy", "ugly" or "awkward". Is it less efficient, not safe, brakes coding practice... I just asking for some pragmatic answer. Maybe understand deeply how things works and for you is "crazy" but for people who learn, they want facts.

Comment: @kat1330 Efficiency is usually not that much of an issue, but why would you add parsing and stringification with no obvious benefit in mind? The purpose of his enum is that it can have only two values. A string can have any number of values. Casting to object and back is bad enough, but at least it's the conventional and relatively simple way of introducing that inconvenience and those bugs. Converting an enum to a string and back is a *weird* way to add inconvenience and bugs.

Comment: @kat1330 **1)** The user is not trying to strore `enum` and `string`. He is trying to store `enum` and `List<String>` so using `string` doesn't make sense.  **2)** When you can use an object to box/unbox values, storing enums as string and converting them back from string does't seem to be efficient. **3)** Sometimes solutions are ugly or awkward based on someone's opinion because they doesn't seem to have any added value. **4)** After all, to me, you seemed more offended rather than curious about the actual reason. That's why I wrote a comment for you, neglect it if you don't like it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a single storage for different types, since the type of values can be determined only at run-time, then you should use `object` type for boxing values and then when you need to work with a value in a typed manner, check for its type and unbox it to desired type and use it.

So you can use one of these data structures based on your requirements:

- `Dictionary<CommandType, object>` ← The key should be unique.
- `List<KeyValuePair<CommandType, object>>` ← There key of pair doesn't need to be unique.

**Note:** You probably can imagine solutions like creating a common base class `BaseType` and derive two different `ListContainer` and `EnumContainer` from the `BaseType` and creating `ListContainer` and `EnumContainer` at runtime and store in a `Dictionary<CommandType, BaseType>`. Such structures probably just can help you to limit the storage to desired type rather than using object.